# Is it true in Mercurial (hg), the same as Git, that a revision you committed may only have code not modified by you? (a merge)

Tags: svn, git, mercurial, dvcs

Seems like in SVN, when you do a merge, there won't be a revision checked in by you.  All your "commits" should only have code that is changed by you.

But in Mercurial, that's not the case.  Your "merge" commits are committed by you, but they usually contain changes that are made by other people.  And if that commit triggered an error in the automated test, then it may be the "merge" that broke the code base, meaning that the other changes didn't work with yours or vice versa?  (but the other changes may not have revealed the error because (1) it may not have gone that far in the test.  (2) the test are batched together -- and if test 102 took 1 hour to run and there are 3 pushes within that hour, then only the last pushed version is tested)

Is this the behavior the same as Git as well?

So you really have to look at the test itself to see what is causing it and fix it... but who should look at it -- you or your team member?

initial encounter of this behavior feels kind of weird...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *merge* will be committed by whoever does it. But you can [bisect](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html) the tree and then [blame](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html) the person that caused the issue. Also if you have idea's of a couple of people who are responsible you should tell them to look at it. If you wrote your tests right they should be giving you some idea of what is wrong where. If their features can't be resolved to both work then you'll have to be diplomatic and make some decisions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are asking about.  When you are joining two lines of development (doing a merge), you will be creating a **merge commit**, i.e. revision representing this act of joining two lines of history.  In Git and Mercurial such commit remembers both parents; in Subversion such revision remembers both revisions for all files (if I understand it correctly).

In most cases the merge commit would be *created **automatically***; in Git (and I think also in Mercurial) using 3-way merge, where the 3rd point (besides tips of both merged lines of development / branches) is common ancestor.  Subversion only lately (since version 1.5, if I remember it correctly) store information required to calculate merge base (without using third party tools such as SVK or svnmerge).  Note that as far as I understand Subversion merges files, while both Git and Mercurial merges revisions as whole.

Sometimes automated merge fails, and you have to *resolve conflicts manually*, and then commit finishing a merge.  This is something that might happen in any version control system.

Independent on whether automated merge succeded or failed, **the act of merging itself (the merge commit in Git and Mercurial) might introduce bugs.**  Take for example situation where one side changes calling convention for some function, and the other side adds another call site with old API.  Automatic merge might succeed, but the merge will introduce error, even though both lines of development are error-free.

Nevertheless [git bisect](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html) can find that it was merge commit (act of merging) that introduced bug.

Comment: maybe you haven't used SVN or CVS before?  I think in those system, a merge is not a separate commit.

Comment: In those version control systems (CVS and Subversion prior to version 1.5) merge was a separate revision, but it didn't remember that it was a merge, i.e. that it came from merging two lines of development (e.g. `cvs update -j ... -j ...` creates a commit, IIRC).